# Get Document source After AJAX or js Action With VB.NET

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, webbrowser-control

When I compare the source code of a webpage in the browser with the source code I get from the code below,

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=778253364357513")

End Sub
   Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Body.InnerHtml
End Sub
```

it differs. The source code is not the same and I suspect that is caused because of some DOM manipulations.

Is it possible to get the HTML source code after the javascript and/or ajax manipulations programmaticly (with VB.NET)?

Comment: Are those code manipulations done after some event on those pages ?

Comment: yes after call js functions some html code added or modified

Comment: i whant get complete html source code of [link]http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=778253364357513[/link] this site with vb
but html code that WebBrowser1.Body.InnerHtml show does not have some part of web site .. can help me ?